# JSON to HTML div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am new to web development and haven't learnt jquery.
I want to convert a JSON output to an HTML user friendly view.

```
{
    "train": {
        "name": "BHOPAL  EXPRESS",
        "days": [
            {
                "day-code": "SUN",
                "runs": "Y"
            },
            {
                "day-code": "MON",
                "runs": "Y"
            },
            {
                "day-code": "TUE",
                "runs": "Y"
            },
            {
                "day-code": "WED",
                "runs": "Y"
            },
            {
                "day-code": "THU",
                "runs": "Y"
            },
            {
                "day-code": "FRI",
                "runs": "Y"
            },
            {
                "day-code": "SAT",
                "runs": "Y"
            }
        ],
        "number": "12155"
    },
    "response_code": 200
}
```

Comment: What is your specific question about this process?

Comment: pls show things you have tried

Comment: mustache.js is all you need

Comment: *I used jQuery and I lost 10kg in just a month.*

Comment: study some tutorials

Comment: Just dynamically create rows depending on the json data and append it to the table..simple huhh :)

Answer (score 2):

You should do like this.

```js
var data = {
  "train": {
    "name": "BHOPAL  EXPRESS",
    "days": [{
      "day-code": "SUN",
      "runs": "Y"
    }, {
      "day-code": "MON",
      "runs": "Y"
    }, {
      "day-code": "TUE",
      "runs": "Y"
    }, {
      "day-code": "WED",
      "runs": "Y"
    }, {
      "day-code": "THU",
      "runs": "Y"
    }, {
      "day-code": "FRI",
      "runs": "Y"
    }, {
      "day-code": "SAT",
      "runs": "Y"
    }],
    "number": "12155"
  },
  "response_code": 200
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#name").text(data.train.name);  
  $.each(data.train.days,function(i,item){
    var tr="<tr>";
    tr+='<td>'+item["day-code"]+'</td>';
    tr+='<td>'+item["runs"]+'</td>';
    tr+='</tr>'
    $("#formatedview").append(tr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="name"></h3>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="formatedview"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use template library(like [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)) to do so.

Here is working example. Just modify the template html on your needs.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <!-- template html -->
    <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <h1>{{train.name}}</h1>
        <ul>
            {{#each train.days}}
            <li>{{day-code}}: {{runs}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </script>
    <script>
        var data = {
            "train": {
            "name": "BHOPAL  EXPRESS",
                    "days": [
                {
                    "day-code": "SUN",
                    "runs": "Y"
                },
                {
                    "day-code": "MON",
                    "runs": "Y"
                },
                {
                    "day-code": "TUE",
                    "runs": "Y"
                },
                {
                    "day-code": "WED",
                    "runs": "Y"
                },
                {
                    "day-code": "THU",
                    "runs": "Y"
                },
                {
                    "day-code": "FRI",
                    "runs": "Y"
                },
                {
                    "day-code": "SAT",
                    "runs": "Y"
                }
            ],
                    "number": "12155"
        },
            "response_code": 200
        };

        var source = $("#template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        $("#result").html(template(data));
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre></pre>

document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, " ", 4);  //auto beautify!
```